# I'm wondering what ip I have to login in terminal by using ssh

Tags: ssh, server, ip, centos7, firewall

I want to know which ip I have when I log in with ssh from the terminal.

Currently, we are building a web server using an internet measurement program called perfsonar.
However, there is no problem with the program, but the web browser is not displayed due to problems such as firewall.

Once I log in with ssh, I want to know what my ip is, and if I log in multiple servers at the same time (login to more than one server with ssh), I want to know what my IP is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, in your SSH session, the environment variable

> ```
> SSH_CONNECTION
> ```
>
> Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.
> The variable contains four space-separated values:
>
> - client IP address,
> - client port number,
> - server IP address, and
> - server port number.

See also "[OpenSSH/Client Applications](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Applications)":

You also have the environment variable:

> ```
> SSH_CLIENT
> ```
>
> shows:
>
> - the address of the client system,
> - the outgoing port number on the client system, and
> - the incoming port on the server.